# Django returns Page Not Found for mapped URL

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to render a basic html/css page in Django and I can't get it to work. It's set up seemingly the same as my index page which does work correctly and the debug explanation from the 404 response seems to show that it's pointing to the right url. Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

*I'm using django 2.1 so I'm using path instead of the old regex url mapping

*The html file exists and is located in templates\base_app\our-story.html

From views.py:

```
def OurStory(request):
    return render(request, 'base_app/our-story.html')
```

From urls.py:

```
from base_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('our-story', views.OurStory, name='our-story')
]
```

From settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    (standard django apps)
    'base_app'
]
```

From debug message:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/our-story.html

Using the URLconf defined in base_app.urls, Django tried these URL 
patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
our-story [name='our-story']
The current path, our-story.html, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Not a django expert by any means (I devops with django devs) but based on that debugging output and your code, I'd think the url you'd want would be  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/our-story`, without the `.html`

Comment: Django means you don't need cruft like `.html` at the end of your URL. If it really is just a static HTML file that you want served, just have a one line view to render the appropriate template, with no context. (Oh, I see you've done that. So your only mistake is entering the wrong URL, and possibly in some links that lead to that page.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL should be - http://127.0.0.1:8000/our-story

We cannot use our-story.html, As we are using framework and already have a route.

Use like this, You will definitely get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess path of html template would be only our-story.html If Your project name is base_app

Answer (score 0):

In views.py you should return:

```
return render(request, template, context)
```

where

```
template = 'our-story.html'
```

and

```
context = { _your_context_dictionary }
```

also it is a good practice to use lower case names in the views:

```
def our_story
```